# Mac rename multiple files at once, removing random numbers

Tags: macos, syntax, file-rename

Without using the terminal, what would the syntax be to "rename" a group of files on Mac by:

1. Removing any and all numbers in the file name:
   For example, names like: "john smith 1978902" or "401873324_Jane_Doe" where the numbers do not represent anything (ie. Find: "[0-9]" and Replace with nothing)
2. Capitalize each word in the file name, so that "john smith" becomes "John Smith"

Comment: If you're not using the terminal, what *are* you using?  In other words, "syntax" in what context?

Comment: write a little program for it.